# div taking properties from each other in html error

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a portfolio page, using HTML, CSS & JS.
Encountered a weird error. The CSS styling that I have performed on one div is somehow also getting on another div. And the weird part is that, the second div responds to its own styling along with the first ones....It will be more clear from the code

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(window).scroll(function() { // of scroll function of windows
        if (this.scrollY > 20) { //if scroll on Y axis is more than 50 units
            $('.navbar').addClass("sticky"); // add sticky class 2 navbar
        } else {
            $('.navbar').removeClass("sticky"); // when it insn't scrolled remove sticky

         }
    });


    //toggle menu/navbar script
    $('.menu-btn').click(function(){ // this activates the inbuilt click function of js on the menu button
        $('.navbar .menu').toggleClass("active");
        $('.menu-btn i').toggleClass("active");


    });


   
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600;700&family=Ubuntu:wght@400;500;700&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@500&display=swap');



*{
    user-select: text;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;    




}

/* navbar styling */

.navbar{ 

    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
    position:fixed;
    padding: 30px 0;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    transition: all 0.55s ease;

}

.navbar.sticky{
    transition: background-color 0.55s ease;
    padding: 15px 0;
    background-color: crimson;
}
.max-width{

    max-width: 1300px;
    padding: 0 80px;
    margin: auto; 
}

.navbar .max-width{

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.navbar .logo a{

    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: cyan;

}



.navbar .logo a span{
    color: cyan
}

.navbar.sticky .logo a span{
    color: white;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;

}


.navbar .menu li{

    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
.navbar .menu li a{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-left: 25px;
    transition: color 0.3s ease;
    
}

.navbar .menu li a:hover{
    color: crimson;
}
    
.navbar.sticky .menu li a:hover{
    color: white;
}

 /* menu button styling */

.menu-btn{
    color: white;
    font-size: 23px;    
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}





/*home section styling */

.home{
    cursor: default;
    display: flex;
    background: url("./Images/wallpapertip_fantasy-art-wallpaper_1940256.jpg") no-repeat center;/* Enter the background image location */
    
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    color: #fff;
    min-height: 500px;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    background-color: black;
    

}


.home .max-width{

    margin: auto 0 auto 40px;


}

.home .home-content .text-1{
    font-size: 27px; 
}

.home .home-content .text-2{
    font-size: 75px; 
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-left: -3px;
}

.home .home-content .text-3{
    font-size: 40px; 
    margin: 5px, 0 ; 
}

.home .home-content .text-3 span{

    color: crimson;
    font-weight: 500;
}

/*    .home .home-content a{
    display: inline-block;
    background: crimson;
    color: white;
    font-size: white;
    padding: 12px 36px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 2px solid crimson;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}    HIRE ME BUTTON STYLE*

.home .home-content a:hover{
    color: crimson;
    background: none; */







/* ABOUT SECTION STYLING */

section{
    padding: 100px 0;
}



.about{

    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    user-select: text;

}

.about .title{
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    color: black;

    
}
.about .title::before{

    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 50%;
    width: 180px;
    height: 3px;
    background: black;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}


.about .title::after{

    content: "who i am";
    position: absolute;
    padding: 5px;
    bottom: -12px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-size: 20px;
    color: crimson;
    background: white;
}

.about .about-content{

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;


}

.about .about-content .left {
    
    width: 45%;
}


.about .about-content .left img{

    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 6px;


}

.about .about-content .right {
    
    width: 55%;
}

.about .about-content .right .text {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: black;
}

.about .about-content .right .text span{
    color: white;

}


.about .about-content .right .lorem{

    color: black;
    background: none;
}




.about .about-content .column  a{

    display: inline-block;
    background: crimson;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 12px 36px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 2px solid crimson;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.about .about-content .right a:hover{
    background: none;
    color: crimson;

}
























    






/* -----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*start media query :start*/

@media(max-width: 1104px){
    .home .max-width{
        margin-left: 0px;
    }

}


@media(max-width: 991px){

    .max-width{
        padding: 0 50px;
        }

}

@media(max-width: 947px){

    

        
    .menu-btn{
        position: fixed;
        display: block;
        z-index: 999;
        color: white;
    }    
        

 

    .navbar .menu{
        position: fixed;
        height:100vh;
        width: 100%;
        left: -100%;
        top: 0;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 80px;
        background: black;
        transition: all 0.3s ease;
    }

    .menu-btn i.active:before{
        content: "\f00d";
    }

    .navbar .menu.active{
        left: 0;
    }

    .navbar .menu li{
        display: block;


    }

    .navbar .menu li a{

        display: inline-block;
        margin:20px 0;
        font-size: 25px;

    }


    .home .home-content .text-2{
        font-size: 70px; 
        
    }
    
    .home .home-content .text-3{
        font-size: 35px; 
    }

    



}


@media(max-width: 690px){
    
    .max-width{
        padding: 0 23px;
        }

    .home .home-content .text-2{
        font-size: 70px; 
        
    }
    
    .home .home-content .text-3{
        font-size: 32px; 
    }
}

@media(max-width: 500px){
    
    

    .home .home-content .text-2{
        font-size: 50px; 
        
    }
    
    .home .home-content .text-3{
        font-size: 32px; 
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">


<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale = 1.0">
    <title> Personal Portfolio Website </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="max-width">
            <div class="logo"><a href="#">Portfo<span>lio.</span></a></div>

            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Home</li>
                <!--navbar -->
                <li><a href="#">About</li>
                <li><a href="#">Skills</li>
                <li><a href=#>Projects</li>
                <li><a href=#>Experience</li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</li>
            </ul>
            <div class="menu-btn">
                <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>


    <!-- home section start -->

    <section class="home" id="home">
        <div class="max-width">
            <div class="home-content">
                <div class="text-1">Hello, my name is</div>
                <div class="text-2">Merlin</div>
                <div class="text-3">And I'm an <span class="typing">Undergrad</span></div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </section>




    <!-- ABOUT SECTION STARTS-->

    <section class="about" id="about">
        <!-- Start Section-->
        <div class="max-width">
            <h2 class="title">About Me</h2>
            <div class="about-content">
                <div class="column left">
                    <img src="./Images/653438.jpg" alt="Image">
                </div>
                <div class="column right">
                    <div class="text">I'm Merlin and I'm an <span class="typing-2">Undergrad</span></div>
                    <div class="lorem">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente, illum quaerat dolores
                            cumque
                            doloribus atque rerum molestiae laborum repudiandae expedita, unde quo, exercitationem
                            consequatur. Hic quas amet, aliquam nihil voluptatem, porro culpa doloremque qui numquam
                            atque
                            rerum. Impedit quisquam animi repellat officia! Expedita officia architecto sed veniam,
                            adipisci
                            cumque molestiae doloribus dolor tenetur maiores nihil explicabo eveniet accusantium quos!
                            Perferendis? </p>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#">Download Resume</a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </section>



















    <script src="./script.js"></script>





</body>

</html>
```

In the About section only the Resume Button is to be highlted but the entire colum right div is somehow affected. When I ran just the About section part, everything worked well. But when I run the whole file the same error pops up. I've tried removing the lorem part from div and put in

and try, still the same error pops up. The same part is somehow referenced to the above the navbar as well, cause when clicked upon it shifts to the navbar. Please look into this.

Comment: I can't see the problem in your snippet, could you post a picture or more description about the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

The error is occurring because you did not close the anchor tags in your menu,
change it to this

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <!--navbar -->
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Skills</a></li>
    <li><a href=#>Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href=#>Experience</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this styling in the about section:

```
.about .about-content .column  a{

    display: inline-block;
    background: crimson;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 12px 36px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 2px solid crimson;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.about .about-content .right a:hover{
    background: none;
    color: crimson;

}
```

That is, every anchor link in the about right part is styled that way - with a crimson background (which changes to crimson text and no background on hover).

Because the anchor tags are not closed in your menu you have anchor tags open (nested anchor tags aren't legal HTML BTW) and it seems the browser is doing its best to understand these open anchor tags. By the time you get to the about section right hand side it still thinks there's an anchor tag (at least, in my Edge on Windows 10 that's what it had put there when I used the dev tools inspect facility to check the actual HTML it's trying to interpret). So it picks up the crimson styling.

Here's the snippet with the anchor tags in the menu closed and the text part of the resume does not have that crimson background:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(window).scroll(function() { // of scroll function of windows
    if (this.scrollY > 20) { //if scroll on Y axis is more than 50 units
      $('.navbar').addClass("sticky"); // add sticky class 2 navbar
    } else {
      $('.navbar').removeClass("sticky"); // when it insn't scrolled remove sticky

    }
  });


  //toggle menu/navbar script
  $('.menu-btn').click(function() { // this activates the inbuilt click function of js on the menu button
    $('.navbar .menu').toggleClass("active");
    $('.menu-btn i').toggleClass("active");


  });



});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600;700&family=Ubuntu:wght@400;500;700&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@500&display=swap');
* {
  user-select: text;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* navbar styling */

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 30px 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  transition: all 0.55s ease;
}

.navbar.sticky {
  transition: background-color 0.55s ease;
  padding: 15px 0;
  background-color: crimson;
}

.max-width {
  max-width: 1300px;
  padding: 0 80px;
  margin: auto;
}

.navbar .max-width {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.navbar .logo a {
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: cyan;
}

.navbar .logo a span {
  color: cyan
}

.navbar.sticky .logo a span {
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.navbar .menu li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar .menu li a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-left: 25px;
  transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

.navbar .menu li a:hover {
  color: crimson;
}

.navbar.sticky .menu li a:hover {
  color: white;
}


/* menu button styling */

.menu-btn {
  color: white;
  font-size: 23px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}


/*home section styling */

.home {
  cursor: default;
  display: flex;
  background: url("./Images/wallpapertip_fantasy-art-wallpaper_1940256.jpg") no-repeat center;
  /* Enter the background image location */
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  color: #fff;
  min-height: 500px;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  background-color: black;
}

.home .max-width {
  margin: auto 0 auto 40px;
}

.home .home-content .text-1 {
  font-size: 27px;
}

.home .home-content .text-2 {
  font-size: 75px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-left: -3px;
}

.home .home-content .text-3 {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 5px, 0;
}

.home .home-content .text-3 span {
  color: crimson;
  font-weight: 500;
}


/*    .home .home-content a{
    display: inline-block;
    background: crimson;
    color: white;
    font-size: white;
    padding: 12px 36px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 2px solid crimson;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}    HIRE ME BUTTON STYLE*

.home .home-content a:hover{
    color: crimson;
    background: none; */


/* ABOUT SECTION STYLING */

section {
  padding: 100px 0;
}

.about {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  user-select: text;
}

.about .title {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  color: black;
}

.about .title::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 180px;
  height: 3px;
  background: black;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.about .title::after {
  content: "who i am";
  position: absolute;
  padding: 5px;
  bottom: -12px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-size: 20px;
  color: crimson;
  background: white;
}

.about .about-content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.about .about-content .left {
  width: 45%;
}

.about .about-content .left img {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.about .about-content .right {
  width: 55%;
}

.about .about-content .right .text {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: black;
}

.about .about-content .right .text span {
  color: white;
}

.about .about-content .right .lorem {
  color: black;
  background: none;
}

.about .about-content .column a {
  display: inline-block;
  background: crimson;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 12px 36px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 2px solid crimson;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.about .about-content .right a:hover {
  background: none;
  color: crimson;
}


/* -----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/


/*start media query :start*/

@media(max-width: 1104px) {
  .home .max-width {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 991px) {
  .max-width {
    padding: 0 50px;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 947px) {
  .menu-btn {
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    z-index: 999;
    color: white;
  }
  .navbar .menu {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    left: -100%;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 80px;
    background: black;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }
  .menu-btn i.active:before {
    content: "\f00d";
  }
  .navbar .menu.active {
    left: 0;
  }
  .navbar .menu li {
    display: block;
  }
  .navbar .menu li a {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px 0;
    font-size: 25px;
  }
  .home .home-content .text-2 {
    font-size: 70px;
  }
  .home .home-content .text-3 {
    font-size: 35px;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 690px) {
  .max-width {
    padding: 0 23px;
  }
  .home .home-content .text-2 {
    font-size: 70px;
  }
  .home .home-content .text-3 {
    font-size: 32px;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 500px) {
  .home .home-content .text-2 {
    font-size: 50px;
  }
  .home .home-content .text-3 {
    font-size: 32px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">


<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale = 1.0">
  <title> Personal Portfolio Website </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="max-width">
      <div class="logo"><a href="#">Portfo<span>lio.</span></a></div>

      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</li>
                <!--navbar -->
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Skills</a></li>
        <li><a href=#>Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href=#>Experience</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="menu-btn">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>


  <!-- home section start -->

  <section class="home" id="home">
    <div class="max-width">
      <div class="home-content">
        <div class="text-1">Hello, my name is</div>
        <div class="text-2">Merlin</div>
        <div class="text-3">And I'm an <span class="typing">Undergrad</span></div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </section>




  <!-- ABOUT SECTION STARTS-->

  <section class="about" id="about">
    <!-- Start Section-->
    <div class="max-width">
      <h2 class="title">About Me</h2>
      <div class="about-content">
        <div class="column left">
          <img src="./Images/653438.jpg" alt="Image">
        </div>
        <div class="column right">
          <div class="text">I'm Merlin and I'm an <span class="typing-2">Undergrad</span></div>
          <div class="lorem">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente, illum quaerat dolores cumque doloribus atque rerum molestiae laborum repudiandae expedita, unde quo, exercitationem consequatur. Hic quas amet, aliquam nihil voluptatem, porro
              culpa doloremque qui numquam atque rerum. Impedit quisquam animi repellat officia! Expedita officia architecto sed veniam, adipisci cumque molestiae doloribus dolor tenetur maiores nihil explicabo eveniet accusantium quos! Perferendis? </p>
          </div>
          <a href="#">Download Resume</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </section>



















  <script src="./script.js"></script>





</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! The thing was driving me crazy and I had a feeling that it was going to be something stupid & it was!!.